# Setting up Flex / AIR project structure for a large number of images?

Tags: css, apache-flex, flex4, air, swc

We build prototypes and demo applications in Flex 4.5.1 and AIR 2.7 for mobile and desktop use.  These tend to involve a large number of full-screen .PNG files. Lately we have been looking at ways to segment our code for flexibility and multi-screen re-use.

What suggestions do people have for segmenting the project and libraries such that compile times are minimal and images are easy to replace?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of strategies pop to mind:

- Externalize the assets from in-line `[Embed]` statements, to using a CSS file.
- Configure the CSS to compile as a seperate SWF, and load it at runtime.  This should minimize the amount of PNG encoding the compiler is doing during your normal compilation process.
- If that still doesn't speed it up enough (I've found that the incremental compiler sometimes gets mixed up and re-encoded the embedded assets, killing compiler speed), move the CSS files to a separate project altogether.

This option is preferable, as loading your images at runtime gives you better flexibility in your multi-screen projects.

Alternatively:

- If using CSS isn't an option for some reason, move your [Embed]'s from your main project to a separate SWC project, and embed them on classes.
- Add the swc as a dependant project
- Reference the assets via the classes.

eg:

```
// assets-project/src/Images.as
public class Images {
    [Embed('/assets/img/defaultAvatar.png')]
    public static var defaultAvatar:Object;
}


// main-project/src/SomeView.mxml
<s:BitmapImage source="{Images.defaultAvatar"} />
```